# How can I make my Angular App 500K or less?

Tags: angular, npm

I've been trying to do some research on this but haven't come to any operational result so far. 
My problem is my Angular application is getting ridiculously big, it's currently 4M in prod and 14M in dev.

I've tried the followings :

- lazy loading a one module which hosts most of the code of the application. This resulted in about 400K off loading when the module gets loaded, but the application is still 3.3M in prod
- Removing unused css, or unused JS files (-200k)

I have another optimization I could do to save 100K but that's about it, so now I'm a bit lost. I searched "how to make Angular smaller" but I can't find a practical solution to do so.

I see a lot of npm modules and not all of them are needed per say - for example I used the Amplify library which adds a lot, and I don't need GraphQL for example in it (I use quiet a lot of other things) but I don't know if it's possible to remove the npm modules, my guess is probably not.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at using [Angular Ivy](https://angular.io/guide/ivy)?

Comment: Yes, I'm already using Angular 9 - Ivy is enabled

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After long research trying to figure out how to make a smaller app, we just decided to move to react because Angular doesn't provide real tools to create small apps on load. We encourage you to do the same !

Answer (score 0):

There is something called lazy loading. You seperate your app in modules and when routing each route loads the module it needs so that not all modules are loaded.[Documentation here](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)

Comment: already done, as explained in my original post, but didn't make much difference, the main page still requires 4MB to load up, which is just unacceptable

Comment: If it is a static page you can try server side rendering